# Debugging a function in C

Tags: c, debugging

This function takes an integer array, the number of elements
    in the array and tries to find a majority element in the
    array.  If the majority element exists, it is placed in
    *result and the function returns true.
    If no majority element exists, then the function returns
    false.  In that case, *result should not be used.

My output isn't working correctly for the program I'm writing and it is because of this findMajority function I think.

This is what the output is supposed to look like: http://pastebin.com/Q5ycXHrg

This is what my output looks like: http://pastebin.com/7P1ZTpML

This is the input:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
1 2 3
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 2
1 1
2
1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Here is the function:

```
int findMajority(int *array, int count, int *result){ 
  int i, counter, bcount = 0, ccount = 0, candidate, j;    

  if(count == 1) {
      *result = *array;
      return true;
  }

  if(count % 2 != 0 ) {
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if(*(array + i) == *(array + count)) {
        counter++;
      }
    }

    if(counter > (count/2)) {
      *result = *(array + count);
      return true;
    }
    else {
      *(array + count) = 0;
      count--;
    }
  }

  for(j=0; j <= count; j += 2) {
    if(*(array + j) == *(array + (j + 1))) {
      *(array + (count + 1)) = *(array + j);
      bcount++;//how many numbers on the end of the array
    }
  }

  if(bcount == 1) {
    int k = count;
    while(*(array + k) == 0) {
      candidate = *(array + k);
    }
  }
  else
    findMajority((array + count), count, result);

  for(j=0; j <= count; j += 2) {
    if(*(array + j) == candidate) {
      ccount++;
    }
  }

  if(ccount > (count/2)) {
    *result = candidate;
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question in your "question"...

Comment: It's quite clear actually. The output I'm producing is incorrect when compared to the intended output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect output in C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169454/incorrect-output-in-c-program). I get that you're trying to improve your question to conform to site requirements, but we'd prefer that you do so by editing your original question (use the `edit` link), not by creating an entirely new question.

Comment: Why are you using code like `*(array + i)` instead of the more usual `array[i]`? Your code could be much easier to read!

Answer (score 1):

Your function has a lot of problem.

1. Without intialising `counter` you are incrementing it
2. check whether `array[count]` is the valid last element or `array[count-1]` is the correct one
3. In this code   `for(j=0; j <= count; j += 2){`

   ```
      if(*(array + j) == *(array + (j + 1))){
          *(array + (count + 1)) = *(array + j);
          bcount++;//how many numbers on the end of the array
      }}
   ```

   for `count= 3` you are accessing `array[4]` `array[5]` etc.
4. And this is a infinite loop. you are not modifying condition variable inside the loop     `while(*(array + k) == 0)        {            candidate = *(array + k);        }`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you learn how to use a debugger to debug your program. For example, after wrapping your code with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { false, true } boolean;

 // ((( your function here )))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int result = 0;
   int number = 0;

   int test[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };


   result = findMajority(&test[0], sizeof(test) / sizeof(int), &number);

   printf("Result = %d, Number = %d\n", result, number);

   return 0;
}
```

Assuming you put this into 'question.c' you could then issue the commands (assuming you have gcc and gdb):

```
$ gcc -g -o question question.c
$ gdb ./question
(gdb) b findMajority
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483ea: file question.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./question
Breakpoint 1, findMajority (array=0xbffff4bc, count=7, result=0xbffff4d8) at question.c:6
6     int i, counter, bcount = 0, ccount = 0, candidate, j;
```

You can then use the `n` command to step to the next line, and the `p` command to print variables to see what's going wrong. For example, you could find some of the problems that Toms pointer out relatively quickly:

```
39     while(*(array + k) == 0){
(gdb) n
40         candidate = *(array + k);
(gdb) n
39     while(*(array + k) == 0){
(gdb) n
40         candidate = *(array + k);
(gdb) n
39     while(*(array + k) == 0){
(gdb) n
```

There's your infinite loop.

```
(gdb) p counter
$3 = -1207959944
```

And there's your uninitialized counter.

Part of learning programming is figuring out strategies of determining just what went wrong. Some people like to use text-based debuggers like `gdb`. Some people like graphical debuggers like you could find in Eclipse CDT. Some people put `printf()` statements throughout their code.

Once you're really good, like Toms, you can just read it and rattle off the problems. ;-)